# SSL issues in CKAN 2.8.2

Tags: ckan

We have `ubuntu 16.04` with `Apache 2.4.39` installed and configured for CKAN application which works on port 80 without any issue when we enable mod_ssl its stops working for both `HTTP` and `https`.

disabling mod_ssl was able to start `ckan` application on `HTTP`, but we need to run same on https.

```
CKAN 2.8.2
```

tried building a new server but the same issue

Comment: Have you tried to use a reverse proxy?

Comment: yes we are using Apache as a reverse proxy in the current enviornment  following the same kind of setup PFB link.(https://github.com/conwetlab/ckanext-oauth2/wiki/Starting-CKAN-over-HTTPs-using-Apache)

Comment: also on apache 2.1.18 when we deployed test wsgi web page same is working , so we came to conlcusion CKAN is not working with latest apache 2.4.39.

Comment: We are currently using 2.4.6 and it is working fine. When you enabled mod_ssl what is the error you are facing? Could you post the apache error logs?

Comment: Error logs would be helpful. Would also be good to see your apache config file and ports file.